# C# linked lists

Tags: c#, linked-list

very basic question, but is there any ToArray-like function for c# linked lists that would return an array of only part of the elements in the linkedlist.

e.g.: let's say my list has 50 items and I need an array of only the first 20. I really want to avoid for loops.

Thanks,

PM

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? Any existing method is going to be using a loop internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `LinkedList` collection class (from `System.Collections.Generic`), you can use LINQ to get it:

```
var myArray = list.Take(20).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Linq?

```
myLinkedList.Take(20).ToArray()
```

*or*

```
myLinkedList.Skip(5).Take(20).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 4):

You say you "really want to avoid for loops" - why?

If you're using .NET 3.5 (or have LINQBridge), it's really easy:

```
var array = list.Take(20).ToArray();
```

... but obviously that will have to loop internally.

Note that this will create a smaller array if the original linked list has fewer than 20 elements. It's unclear whether or not that's what you want.

*Something* is going to have to loop internally, sooner or later - it's not like there's going to be a dedicated CPU instruction for "navigate this linked list and copy a fixed number of pointers into a new array". So the question is really whether you do it or a library method.

If you can't use LINQ, it's pretty easy to write the equivalent code yourself:

```
int size = Math.Min(list.Count, 20);
MyType[] array = new MyType[size];
var node = list.First;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    array[i] = node.Value;
    node = node.Next;
}
```

That will actually be slightly more efficient than the LINQ approach, too, because it creates the array to be exactly the right size to start with. Yes, it uses a loop - but as I say, *something's* got to.

Comment: I don't mind the internal looping I just missed the Take method while going through the linked-list method list. I got caught up on Select, which is really not what I need.